Are memories henceforth forgotten after the last time they are recollected?
Consider the final time you will ever recollect a certain memory. Can we thus consider this memory to be forgotten from that point forward?
There is an obvious difference between a memory that isn't being recalled at any point in time to one that is forgotten. Just because a memory isn't being recalled right now doesn't mean that it won't ever be in the future, or that it is forgotten. But if we can know when the last moment a memory will be recalled, can we say that it is then forgotten? There is a sense in which after the final time a memory is recollected it is as though it is henceforth forgotten, in that a memory that is remembered but never again recollected is indistinguishable from a forgotten one.
My doubt about this is this: memories can be seen as being stored in the mind as a kind of "recollection potential", in that they sit in the brain dormant until the mind wishes to recall it. If a memory is not forgotten, it is available to be recalled. Consider again the final time a certain memory is ever recollected; the memory might still be sat dormant in the brain, not forgotten, and available to be recalled - except it simply won't ever again.
Any comments on how to answer or progress this question are greatly appreciated.

It isn't forgotten until you can no longer retrieve it. And even then, it may still be present and just harder to access, misplaced rather than discarded.

"If we can know when the last moment a memory will be recalled, can we say that it is then forgotten?" If " forgotten" means "cannot be recalled" and "can" has its common meaning then no, that would be a modal fallacy. Just because something does not happen does not mean that it cannot happen, even if we know somehow that it never does actually happen. However, there are philosophers who assert that there is a single possible future and possible reduces to actual, see Actualism.

From practical point of view a memory could be physically maintained without being able to be accessed, such as a bad sector in memory storage. The path to that memory has been corrupted and the conscious or subconscious mind is unable to access it because its path is inhibited. Whether memory is physical, spiritual or both would be the limiting factors in my analysis.

It only depends on definitions, and this is not a good question.

You are implicitly assuming that single memories are like separate 'things', like stones in a riverbed hardly affected by the stream and not having a real impact on the stream. And as if "retrieving" a memory would be like picking up one of those stones.
But even stones are affected and have an impact on the stream and on other stones in it -- even a stone (memory trace) that is never retrieved, sinking away in the mud. I believe we don't yet have a satisfactory theory of memory (in mammals, let alone in humans) but we do have certain mathematical models (like Pentti Kanerva's beautiful sparse distributed memory) that can (partially) explain for instance how retrieving a memory may ipso facto change a memory or how/where one memory is stored may affect how/where other memories are stored (and how they are retrieved). In other words, the simplistic model of retrieval as if you're picking up single stones from a little stream without thereby shaping the stone -- which is implicitly suggested by the question -- does not at all do justice to the fluidity of memory and the way memory and cognition are intertwined.
Even though we don't have a complete theory (neurological/mathematical), it seems clear that our memory must be a content-addressable memory. This by itself makes it very different from everyday notions of "retrieval" or "storage" (and very different from normal computer memory which does conform to those everyday notions, assuming a sharp distinction between the data -- the memory content space -- and memory locations -- the address space). "Forgetting" is also no longer the same as a simple inability to no longer being able to find "something" back. Forgetting may require work (even though we're not aware of it).

This brings to the fore the question "what is a memory?", and given your tagging the question as philosophy of psychology, you are approaching this from a biological perspective. A folk psychological approach is to think of memories as items in a container, the container being our brain or mind. A more sophisticated approach might see memories as neurological structures or the process of activating those structures.
According to WP's article on memory:

Memory is the faculty of the mind by which data or information is encoded, stored, and retrieved when needed. It is the retention of information over time for the purpose of influencing future action.1 If past events could not be remembered, it would be impossible for language, relationships, or personal identity to develop.

Here we see that memory is conceptualized as a psychological faculty, and this is in line with the traditional notions of faculty psychology. From WP:

Faculty psychology is the idea that the mind is separated into faculties or sections, and that each of these faculties is assigned to certain mental tasks. Some examples of the mental tasks assigned to these faculties include judgment, compassion, memory, attention, perception, and consciousness. For example, we can speak because we have the faculty of speech or we can think because we have the faculty of thought. 1 Thomas Reid mentions over 43 faculties of the mind that work together as a whole. Additionally, faculty psychology claims that we are born with separate, innate human functions.

So, if a memory is the experiential product of the act of recollection of an individual's past, and that person loses the ability to recollect or dies, then yes, memories are gone and forgotten. Even more illuminating is that memories can be the subject of confabulation, and therefore, arguably can be forgotten when the particulars are altered but the entire ability to recollect is not lost. This leads down the path of identity of memories, and issues like sorites paradox complicate the issue.
A fascinating story of how memories impact our life is told in Memory's Ghost (GB). It's a case study of Henry Molaison, whose memory was impacted by surgery:

an American who had a bilateral medial temporal lobectomy to surgically resect the anterior two thirds of his hippocampi, parahippocampal cortices, entorhinal cortices, piriform cortices, and amygdalae in an attempt to cure his epilepsy. Although the surgery was partially successful in controlling his epilepsy, a severe side effect was that he became unable to form new memories.

